# MySQL query resulting in the substraction of the sum of 2 columns in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL DB with the following Tables:

**Products**:

```
Product_ID | Product_Name
     1     |     Blaster
     2     |     Faser
     3     |     BFG
```

**Orders**:

```
Order_ID | Product_ID | Order_Product_Qnt
    1    |     1      |        10
    2    |     2      |        5
    3    |     3      |        7
    4    |     2      |        10
```

**Sells**:

```
Sell_ID | Product_ID | Sel_Product_Qnt
    1   |      2     |        5
    2   |      1     |        1
    3   |      3     |        2
```

What I want to do is a query that lists all the products followed by their amount.

The result should be:

```
Product_Name | Quantity
BFG          |    5
Blaster      |    9
Faser        |    10
```

Following Barnar's suggestion I got to this piece of code:

```
SELECT 
    Products.Product_Name,
    COALESCE (SUM(Orders.Order_Product_Qnt), 0) - COALESCE (SUM(Sells.Sells_Product_Qnt), 0) AS Quantity
FROM 
    Products
LEFT JOIN 
    Orders ON Products.Product_ID = Orders.Product_ID
LEFT JOIN 
    Sells ON Products.Product_ID = Sells.Product_ID
GROUP BY 
    Products.Product_Name
```

The query works but it returns wrong values.

For example, I have a product that has 6 orders, and 1 sell, logic dictates that 6-1=5, but that query gives me 4 as a result.

Or another one with 18 Orders and 6 Sells, returns 60 (should be 12).

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: Join the tables, and subtract `SUM(Sel_Product_Qant)` from `SUM(Order_Product_Qnt)`.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I'll try to do that.

Comment: I keep searching for the answer on Google and still hit a brick wall... anyone?

Comment: And what is the result of your query? It looks OK

Comment: Ah, there is one problem. Use `left join` instead of `inner join`.

Comment: Still not working with LEFT JOIN, although I do get all Product_Names if I remove the COALESCE line. So I assume the problem resides in the COALESCE line.

Comment: As usual... SQL is always right. I had one of my Tables miss-typed. But the general guidelines given from you guys did point me into the right direction.

Comment: After all it is still not working.
For some reason the subtraction is not working properly. For example, I have a product that has 6 orders, and 1 sell, logic dictates that 6-1=5, but that query gives me 4 as a result.
I've been thinkering with the joins and aparently the problem resides there, but I have no clue on how to fix it... anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working, forgot to post my solution here:

```
    SELECT
        Products.Product_ID,
        Products.Product_Name,
        IFNULL(b.SB - c.SC, 0) AS Quantity,
   FROM Produtos_Table
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                Product_ID,
                SUM(Quantity) AS SB
            FROM
                Orders 
            GROUP BY Product_ID
        ) b 
        ON Products.Product_ID = b.Product_ID
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                Product_ID,
                SUM(Sell_Product_Qnt) AS SC 
            FROM 
                Sells
            GROUP BY 
                Product_ID
        ) c
        ON Products.Product_ID = c.Product_ID
   GROUP BY
        Products.Product_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT 
product_name,
orders_cnt - sales_cnt AS Quantity
FROM (
    SELECT product_name,
    SUM(orders) AS orders_cnt,
    SUM(sales) AS sales_cnt
    FROM (
        SELECT products.product_name,
        ifnull(orders.order_product_qnt, 0) orders,
        ifnull(sells.sells_product_qnt,0) sales
    FROM products
    LEFT JOIN orders ON products.product_id = orders.product_id
    LEFT JOIN sells ON products.product_id = sells.product_id
    ) t1
GROUP BY product_name ) t2
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew but still no luck.
Just tried your query with no result, I see you mention "sales" on the second "ifnull", did you meant "sells" or you typed "sells" in the 2º LEFT JOIN wen you wanted "sales"?